# Attribute Routing vs Convention

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Playing around with the Web.API 2.0 stuff- in particular Attribute Routing.  The [docs](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) state that you can have attribute routing AND the 1.0 routing by convention... but these two don't seem to play that well together.  For example, given these two methods:

```
public override HttpResponseMessage PutModel(SampleForm form)

[HttpPut("approvesampleform/{form}")]
public string ApproveSampleForm([FromBody]SampleForm form)
```

While I can call `http://localhost/api/sampleform/approvesampleform` just fine, a `PUT` to `http://localhost/api/sampleform/` generates a `Multiple actions were found that match the request` error.

Is there any way that if a method is marked with the attribute routing it is ignored by the convention?  This would be ideal... but I don't see any way to accomplish this in the docs.

Note: I don't see a asp.net-web-api-2 tag.  Perhaps someone with more than 1500 rep can create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, RC (Release Candidate) did not have the logic where conventional routes cannot access attributed controller/actions. This change came post-RC. The scenario you are trying would work fine in post-RC bits.

Probably the docs you mentioned aren't very clear, but I think they mean that you could have attributed and convention based controllers work side-by-side and not particularly about mixing both attributed and conventional semantics in the same controller.

For time being you could probably use only attribute routing for your controller mentioned above.

Comment: Where can I find those bits (if I can) I'm using the RC1 version.

Comment: I will let you know soon about this soon.